# 'P" "'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, unix

i am trying to run `.bat` file from command line , which calls a `UNIX` shell script, earlier it was working all fine, and suddenly now i am getting this issue when i run `.bat` from command line, it also comes at very specific line.

**Error-:**

```
'P" "'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Bat File-:**

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set vector[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)


SET admPath=%vector[0]%
SET admdatatype=%vector[1]%
SET admeaimethod=%vector[2]%
SET admprefix=%vector[3]%
SET gatewayname=%vector[4]%
SET enterpriseName=%vector[5]%
SET serverName=%vector[6]%
SET serveruserId=%vector[7]%
SET serverpassword=%vector[8]%
SET userId=%vector[9]%
SET password=%vector[10]%
SET host=%vector[11]%
SET sudoUser=%vector[12]%
SET localPath=%vector[13]%
SET admFilter=%vector[14]%

echo %admPath%
echo %admdatatype%
echo %admeaimethod%
echo %admprefix%
echo %gatewayname%
echo %enterpriseName%
echo %serverName%
echo %serveruserId%
echo %serverpassword%
echo %userId%
echo %password%
echo %host%
echo %sudoUser%
echo %localPath%
echo %admFilter%


echo y | "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh %userId%@%host% -pw %password% exit

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh -t %userId%@%host% -pw %password% "/opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/ExportLov.sh %admPath% %admdatatype% %admeaimethod% %admprefix% %gatewayname% %enterpriseName% %serverName% %serveruserId% %serverpassword% %admFilter% %password% %sudoUser% %localPath% " > LovExport_Status.txt 2>&1
```

In above code if a remove the last line, i can't see that error printed on console, but when i keep that line , i get the above mentioned error in output file.It was working all fine before, i am not getting why i am getting this issue now. Please help.

**UNIX SCRIPT-:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
admPath=$1
admdatatype=$2
admeaimethod=$3
admprefix=$4
gatewayname=$5
enterpriseName=$6
serverName=$7
userId=$8
password=$9
admFilter=${10}
serverPassword=${11}
serverSudoUser=${12}
localPath=${13}

echo "$admPath"
echo "$admdatatype"
echo "$admeaimethod"
echo "$admprefix"
echo "$gatewayname"
echo "$enterpriseName"
echo "$userId"
echo "$password"
echo "$admFilter"
echo "$serverPassword"
echo "$serverSudoUser"
echo "$serverName"
echo "$localPath"

echo "$serverPassword" | sudo -S -l
sudo $serverSudoUser  <<EOF
./exportLOV.sh "$admPath" "$admdatatype" "$admeaimethod" "$admprefix" "$gatewayname" "$enterpriseName" "$serverName" "$userId" "$password" '$admFilter' "$localPath"
EOF
```

I have checked enviornment variable for windows, it looks good because error comes at specific line , i guess the issue is something else.

> Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: why do you set the `vector` variables there? simply use `%1`, `%2`... for `vector[1]`, `vector[2]`... and remove `echo off` to see where the error happens

Comment: @Luu Vinh Phuc let me test without echo, I will update you back

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc What should i check after setting echo off?

Comment: probably you have a poison character in one of the passwords (I guess in `%serverpassword%`, as the line before with `%password%` seems to execute without error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of string values of the environment variables referenced on command line

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh -t %userId%@%host% -pw %password% "/opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/ExportLov.sh %admPath% %admdatatype% %admeaimethod% %admprefix% %gatewayname% %enterpriseName% %serverName% %serveruserId% %serverpassword% %admFilter% %password% %sudoUser% %localPath% " > LovExport_Status.txt 2>&1
```

contain `&` or `|` which have special meanings if the argument string containing this character is not enclosed in straight double quotes, see [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/).

Argument strings containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|> `` must be enclosed in double quotes to get interpreted the entire argument string as literal string.

So I strongly recommend:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh -t "%userId%@%host%" -pw "%password%" "/opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/ExportLov.sh %admPath% %admdatatype% %admeaimethod% %admprefix% %gatewayname% %enterpriseName% %serverName% %serveruserId% %serverpassword% %admFilter% %password% %sudoUser% %localPath% " > LovExport_Status.txt 2>&1
```

`%userId%@%host%` and `%password%` are also enclosed in double quotes.

I suppose the string value of environment variable `password` contains an ampersand or vertical bar and next non space character is `p` resulting in the error message on execution of the batch file.

The cause of the error can be seen by inserting above last line `echo on` and run the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file.

I recommend also reading answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) on assigning strings to environment variables containing `&` or `|` or other characters with a special meaning on command line if not being enclosed in a double quoted string and the environment variables are referenced with expansion during preprocessing phase of Windows command interpreter before command execution instead of usage of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: Yes you are correct i have " | " in my password, so that might b e causing me this issue.